H-bridge with two logic-level GPIOs drawing high current
I am working on controlling a bi-stable latching solenoid with an H-bridge.
The microcontroller that I am using for my project doesn't have enough GPIOs for me to use four pins for the H-bridge, so I designed a circuit with PNP and NPN transistors:

I tested the circuit in simulation before making my board and it appeared to work. Setting H1B to high set the direction of the voltage correctly and vice versa.
I built my PCB and discovered that when 24 V is applied to the power rail, my power supply goes into constant current mode (even when H1D and H1B are both at 0 V). I added some control to the H1D and H1B lines but can't get either of them to close Q13 or Q10.
What could be causing this to short with H1D and H1B both low? Do you see any issues with this circuit?
Latest Simulation
I rebuilt the model in LTspice to get more accurate component models. I am seeing some strange behavior. The solenoid+ is seeing 12 V before any FETs are opened. How would that happen? I also moved the PNP resistors to below the NPN so that they don't pull any current and activate PNP. Changing the diodes to VS-E5TH1506 fast-recovery diodes helped bring the end voltage back to 12 V.




No pull-ups on H1A and H1D and no provision for dead time while switching.

Also need large electrolytic (1000μF?) in parallel with a ceramic (0.1μF?) from 24V to ground.

Thanks @RussellH I tried adding the pullups in the simulation but it has the same response to GPIO. Could you explaind what the caps are for?
https://tinyurl.com/33fcba7t

@RussellH I also tried pulling them up to 3v3 and that caused it to stop working: https://tinyurl.com/2uv2pk57

Edit in the screenshots to the original question. Please don't make people dig down through comments and click on a random link that could go anywhere.

@vir added the pictures of the new sims and links above to make it easier

Pull-up to 3.3V will leave your PNPs on constantly, as you saw; 24V is the correct voltage. You can try implementing this on a breadboard and see if it gives acceptable performance. You still have a lack of dead time issue but it might be good enough as is. I recommend using a dual half-bridge chip with integrated transistors. You can control them with two logic lines.

When the solenoid is turned off, the inductance will maintain the current as the field collapses. Since the transistors are turned off, the current will pass through a pair of diodes reversed into the power supply. To protect the power supply, and to reduce 24V fluctuation, a low and a high frequency capacitor must be placed between across the 24V close to the bridg

The pull-up resistors are vir's suggestion. I edited the question to reflect.

What is V(Solenoid+,Solenoid-)? What is the significance of this measurement vs. the V(Solenoid+) shown?

@sdolan I suggest that you undelete the original text and images and create a new question for your new problems. Your new questions/problems do not match the title of the original question.


I tested the circuit in simulation before making my board and it appeared to work. Setting H1B to high set the direction of the voltage correctly and vice versa.

No, your circuit in the simulator does not work correctly. It appeared to work because you used the default diodes with a lot of leakage current. I suggest replacing them with 1N4004 diodes. Another bigger problem in your simulation is the use of a voltmeter in place of the solenoid. This makes the Solenoid+ and Solenoid- terminals open. To remedy that, put an inductor to represent the solenoid (see the image below).


What could be causing this to short with H1D and H1B both low? Do you see any issues with this circuit?

You missed the base resistors on both PNP transistors. Without them, H1A and H1C are shorted to GND when both bottom-most NPN transistors are turned ON, as you have observed.
Here is the amended circuit.

Edit
In your actual circuit, please avoid using 1N4004 diodes due to their slow reverse recovery time. Instead, consider using diodes like the ES1A. I suggested 1N4004 above because the Falstad simulator does not have many other options.
Adding a pull-up resistor at the base of each PNP transistor, as suggested by Vir (and highlighted by RussellH), can slightly improve turn-off time. This is due to faster removal of excess charge carriers in the base region through the resistor when the PNP transistor is turned OFF. However, it’s acceptable not to add the resistor if you’re using NPN like the 2N3904 and 2N2222 for those bottom most transistors (left and right). These NPN transistors have very low collector leakage current (5nA to 50nA). The resistor is needed if the collector leakage current is significant; otherwise, the PNP transistor might partially turn ON even when the NPN transistor is OFF.
Regarding the solenoid, I didn’t include coil resistance in my previous suggestion because my intention was to identify the issues and provide minimal adjustments to get the simulation running correctly.

The solenoid will have a series resistance as well. Dead time is still required.

You also still need the pull-ups suggested by @vir

@RussellH some deadtime could easily be added in the firmware right?

@RussellH thanks for all the help. I added another diagram above to show what i thought you meant by deadtime (DT). I was reading online after your comment that we just need to make neither high or low side switches are open with their partner high side/low side. here's the draw io diagram if you want to mark that up: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Q2MJSsZn2nQOmVyzkqUrF6EIOOnC3Fqn/view?usp=sharing

@RussellH Thanks. I have edited my answer. The OP indicated he wished to control the dead-time separately in software/firmware and was not included in his simulation. So, I just addressed his main question (see the title).

@sdolan Yes, you can handle the dead-time in your firmware. Just measure how long it takes for the PNP to shutoff completely and that would be the minimum dead-time. Take note that if you change to different PNP, you need to measure again because it might be different.

@RussellH Referring to my annotated schematic, if H1B and H1D are set to 3.3V and 0V, respectively, then Q3 and Q4 are ON and OFF, respectively. Also, Q5 and Q6 are ON and OFF, respectively too. Q5 and Q6 turn Q1 and Q2 OFF and ON, respectively.  In short, Q2 and Q3 are both ON and Q1 and Q4 are both OFF. I don't see how shoot-through can happen.

@RussellH That is the reason for adding dead-time between H1B and H1D to avoid shoot-through.

Sorry, You are right. I withdraw my comments

@kaosad i edit the original post with the truth table you mentioned and rebuilt the model in LTsprice. i don't really get why the solenoid sees 12V when both GPIO are low.

@sdolan The reason for voltage discrepancy is because the solenoid coil resistance is 17Ω and at 24V the current can reach ~1.4A. But, MMBT5401 and BC817 are only rated for ~0.5A. You either change to 2A or 3A BJT or MOSFET.

@kaosad The coil shouldn't have any current before the GPIO turns on though right? In the simulation the H1B isn't turned on until 100ms after T0

@sdolan I apologize for misreading your question. When both inputs are low (GND), the voltages stabilize and settle midway between 0V and 24V due to the transistors’ output resistance acting as a potential divider. I presume the simulator treats the cut-off output resistance of the transistors the same, resulting in the midway voltage. The penultimate answer I gave above was to address your new waveform picture with the question "why is this not 0 or 24V?"

@sdolan I suggest undeleting the original text and images and creating a new question for your new problems. Your new questions or problems do not match the title of the original question. Anyone who reads this question will be confused by the Q&A.

With only two more transistors (eight vs six in your circuit), only one GPIO pin is needed to drive the solenoid. The GPIO pin has three states: INPUT, OUTPUT HIGH, OUTPUT LOW.

INPUT: solenoid off, 150μW power consumption.
OUTPUT HIGH: solenoid +
OUTPUT LOW: solenoid -

The firmware has to be written such that direct transitions between the OUTPUT states are not possible, but rather the INPUT state is always transitioned.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Q1 and Q2 are current switches that steer GPIO pin current through either R6 (OUTPUT LOW) or R7 (OUTPUT HIGH). Q3 and Q6 get turned on in the respective states. R8 and R11 drive the bridge switches Q4 and Q5 during the OUTPUT LOW state. R12 and R15 drive the bridge switches Q7 and Q8 during OUTPUT HIGH.
The flyback diodes can be back-to-back Zeners as shown, or switching diodes to rails as in your original design.
The solenoid can be driven with about 20-30mA of current. As shown, the driver thus supports 0.5W coil power rating. For higher coil power ratings, the resistors R8..R15 need to be adjusted.

This is very interesting. Is there any advantage to this design verse the above besides saving a pin? It seems more complex wrt qty of components and software. You mentioned the power consumption, i didn't measure my circuits consumption yet, but do you expect it to be >150 µW when the solenoid is off?
Very interesting design regardless.

The advantage is it was fun to design, and uses only one pin. Software is easy, and complexity of this circuit in the days of cad is not making much difference. With two GPIO pins the circuit will be the same, just the front current switch will be split in two and polarity of control of one side of the H will need to change. Then it will treat INPUT and LOW the same. An additional transistor would protect from inadvertent cross conduction. As shown cross conduction is transient at most.
